# many similarly phrased questions

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, methods

#when I type this I get an error and I cant figure it out. What I want is a random selection from the list.

```
import random
movies = ["pulp fiction", "peter pan", "toy story"]
watch = random.choice[movies]
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 watch = random.choice[movies]

> TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Can you choose a different title for this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

You used square bracket instead of parentheses.
Change your last line into :-

```
watch = random.choice(movies)
```